# read a JSON file and format it to CSV

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have to read a json file and extract the data to generate a CSV file.

Server is Redhat 7, python is Python 2.7.5

```
import time
import os
import sys
import json

with open('abcdc04_abcd11_ig_Host_metrics.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)


with open('abcdc04_abcd11_ig_Host_metrics.txt', 'w') as f:

    for row in data:
        symmetrixID= row['symmetrixID']
        HostID= row['HostID']
        HostMBReads= row['HostMBReads']
        timestamp= row['timestamp']
        joined = ",".join([symmetrixID , HostID, HostMBReads , timestamp])
        f.write(joined)
```

The result is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./json_scv", line 23, in <module>
    symmetrixID= row['symmetrixID']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

My input json file is this:

```
{
  "symmetrixID": "000123401234",
  "HostID": "jupiter_ig",
  "perf_data": [
    {
      "HostMBReads": 0.00024720083,
      "timestamp": 1553637300000,
      "Writes": 0.0,
      "ReadResponseTime": 0.15273508,
      "Reads": 0.06328341,
      "WriteResponseTime": 0.0,
      "ResponseTime": 0.15273508,
      "SyscallCount": 0.09326678,
      "HostMBWrites": 0.0,
      "HostIOs": 0.06328341,
      "MBs": 0.00024720083
    },
    {
      "HostMBReads": 0.0004939684,
      "timestamp": 1553637600000,
      "Writes": 0.0,
      "ReadResponseTime": 0.15828949,
      "Reads": 0.1264559,
      "WriteResponseTime": 0.0,
      "ResponseTime": 0.15828949,
      "SyscallCount": 0.123128116,
      "HostMBWrites": 0.0,
      "HostIOs": 0.1264559,
      "MBs": 0.0004939684
    },
    {
      "HostMBReads": 0.0,
      "timestamp": 1553637900000,
      "Writes": 0.0,
      "ReadResponseTime": 0.0,
      "Reads": 0.0,
      "WriteResponseTime": 0.0,
      "ResponseTime": 0.0,
      "SyscallCount": 0.2,
      "HostMBWrites": 0.0,
      "HostIOs": 0.0,
      "MBs": 0.0
    }
  ],
  "reporting_level": "Host"
}
```

I want to have a csv format look like this:

```
SymmID,HostName,TimeStamp,HostIOs,HostMBs,ResponseTime,Reads,Writes,HostMBReads,HostMBWrites,ReadResponseTime,WriteResponseTime SyscallCount
000123401234,jupiter_ig,1553637600000,0.12666667,0.000494792,0.15257895,0.12666667,0,0.000494792,0,0.15257895,0,0.21333334
000123401234,jupiter_ig, 1553637600000,0.1264559,0.000493968,0.15828949,0.1264559,0,0.000493968,0,0.15828949,0,0.123128116
000123401234,jupiter_ig,1553637600000,0 ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.2
```

Comment: After `data = json.load(data_file)`, the variable `data` contains a Python dictionary, so the `for row in data:` is iterating of the _keys` of that dictionary — in other words, it's not a list.

Comment: Max: Glad you understood my mangled comment — as often happens when I type too quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable by the name of `data` should end up being a dictionary, not a list.  So when you try to do "`for row in data:`", you're saying "Do the following for each key in the dictionary", **not** for items in a list!  Dictionaries are not ordered, but regardless of which key first gets picked as `row`, the command fails because it can't find anything called "`symmetrixID`" inside of it.  If `HostID` for example was the first key picked in the loop, then `row['symmetrixID']` means `data['HostID']['symmetrixID']`.

If you look more closely, there's only one list in the dictionary to iterate through, and that's `data["perf_data"]`.  So try the loop there.

So sticking your data in a string for the moment:

```
s = """
{
  "symmetrixID": "000123401234", 
  "HostID": "jupiter_ig", 
  "perf_data": [
    {
      "HostMBReads": 0.00024720083, 
      "timestamp": 1553637300000, 
      "Writes": 0.0, 
      "ReadResponseTime": 0.15273508, 
      "Reads": 0.06328341, 
      "WriteResponseTime": 0.0, 
      "ResponseTime": 0.15273508, 
      "SyscallCount": 0.09326678, 
      "HostMBWrites": 0.0, 
      "HostIOs": 0.06328341, 
      "MBs": 0.00024720083
    }, 
    {
      "HostMBReads": 0.0004939684, 
      "timestamp": 1553637600000, 
      "Writes": 0.0, 
      "ReadResponseTime": 0.15828949, 
      "Reads": 0.1264559, 
      "WriteResponseTime": 0.0, 
      "ResponseTime": 0.15828949, 
      "SyscallCount": 0.123128116, 
      "HostMBWrites": 0.0, 
      "HostIOs": 0.1264559, 
      "MBs": 0.0004939684
    }, 
    {
      "HostMBReads": 0.0, 
      "timestamp": 1553637900000, 
      "Writes": 0.0, 
      "ReadResponseTime": 0.0, 
      "Reads": 0.0, 
      "WriteResponseTime": 0.0, 
      "ResponseTime": 0.0, 
      "SyscallCount": 0.2, 
      "HostMBWrites": 0.0, 
      "HostIOs": 0.0, 
      "MBs": 0.0
    }
  ], 
  "reporting_level": "Host"
}
"""
```

Here's how I got the data to format:

```
import json
data = json.loads(s)

symmetrixID= data['symmetrixID']
HostID= data['HostID']
for row in data['perf_data']:
    HostMBReads = row['HostMBReads']
    timestamp = row['timestamp']
    joined = ",".join([str(c) for c in [symmetrixID, HostID, HostMBReads, timestamp]])
    print(joined)
```

Notice that I changed your `joined` expression.  If you don't change all of those float values to strings first, the `join` won't work.  Regardless, you can replace the `print` command with the writing command you need.

Comment: Thanks Bill, but now i have this :   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./1json_scv", line 21, in <module>
    data = json.loads(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

Comment: There's a difference between json.load() and json.loads().  One takes a file path as input, whereas the other takes a string as input.  If you're using json.loads() and not json.load(), are you sure your input is a string?

Comment: this is my modification as you sugested                              
import json


with open('nameemc04_namecws11_ig_Host_metrics.json') as s:
          data = json.loads(s)


with open('nameemc04_namecws11_ig_Host_metrics.txt', 'w') as f:


 symmetrixID= data['symmetrixID']
 HostID= data['HostID']
for row in data['perf_data']:
    HostMBReads = row['HostMBReads']
    timestamp = row['timestamp']
    joined = ",".join([str(c) for c in [symmetrixID, HostID, HostMBReads, timestamp]])
    print(joined)

Comment: When you use the variable `s` in the syntax of `open(somefile.json') as s:`, then `s` is neither the file's filepath, nor a string of the file's contents.  Again, `json.loads()` is looking for a string as input.  You may want to read up on the proper syntax of Python's `open` command: https://pythontips.com/2014/01/15/the-open-function-explained/

Comment: Bill it worked thanks   , i started python  only 3 weeks a go the result is good    now      000197802257,namecws11_ig,0.00024720083,1553637300000
000197802257,namecws11_ig,0.0004939684,1553637600000
000197802257,namecws11_ig,0.0,1553637900000

Comment: Great!  If you liked my reply, please consider marking it as the "accepted" answer.  You'll get points added to your reputation score when you do.

Comment: thanks if you are ok with another question same task but the report generated is little different let me know

Comment: Thanks for the checkmark! As for another question on this same task, you may want to post it as a new question. That way if it's something that may help others in the future, they'll find it via searching when they search for a similar problem they may be having.

Comment: you are right i open a new one thanks for your precious help